# Angular 2 array: categorize into data sets based on user input

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, filtering

I am trying to loop through this data source
http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml

I have converted the xml response to JSON successfully but am struggling to categorize the response into date sets.

So basically I am trying to loop through the array and if a user enters a date which exists in the array, then only use that respective data set(index).

eg. if user selects this date "20170811" then I only want data set(currencies, rates) for "20170811"

Here is my code
//TS

```
this.forexDataService.getData().then((data) => {
 this.data = data;
 for(var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++){
   this.time = this.data[i].time;
   console.log(this.time);
 }
});
```

//HTML

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="Date" (ionChange)='date($event)' name="date">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let item of data" [value]="item.time">{{item.time}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

//JSON sample

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "time": "20170811",
      "Cube": [
        {
          "currency": "USD",
          "rate": "1.1765"
        },
        {
          "currency": "JPY",
          "rate": "128.41"
        },
        {
          "currency": "BGN",
          "rate": "1.9558"
        },
        {
          "currency": "CZK",
          "rate": "26.155"
        },
        {
          "currency": "DKK",
          "rate": "7.437"
        },
        {
          "currency": "GBP",
          "rate": "0.90645"
        },
        {
          "currency": "HUF",
          "rate": "305.41"
        },
        {
          "currency": "PLN",
          "rate": "4.2888"
        },
        {
          "currency": "RON",
          "rate": "4.5778"
        },
        {
          "currency": "SEK",
          "rate": "9.6083"
        },
        {
          "currency": "CHF",
          "rate": "1.132"
        },
        {
          "currency": "NOK",
          "rate": "9.3975"
        },
        {
          "currency": "HRK",
          "rate": "7.3982"
        },
        {
          "currency": "RUB",
          "rate": "70.6275"
        },
        {
          "currency": "TRY",
          "rate": "4.1765"
        },
        {
          "currency": "AUD",
          "rate": "1.4962"
        },
        {
          "currency": "BRL",
          "rate": "3.7378"
        },
        {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "rate": "1.4956"
        },
        {
          "currency": "CNY",
          "rate": "7.8414"
        },
        {
          "currency": "HKD",
          "rate": "9.1992"
        },
        {
          "currency": "IDR",
          "rate": "15722.96"
        },
        {
          "currency": "ILS",
          "rate": "4.2171"
        },
        {
          "currency": "INR",
          "rate": "75.496"
        },
        {
          "currency": "KRW",
          "rate": "1346.47"
        },
        {
          "currency": "MXN",
          "rate": "21.1711"
        },
        {
          "currency": "MYR",
          "rate": "5.0531"
        },
        {
          "currency": "NZD",
          "rate": "1.6149"
        },
        {
          "currency": "PHP",
          "rate": "60.033"
        },
        {
          "currency": "SGD",
          "rate": "1.6052"
        },
        {
          "currency": "THB",
          "rate": "39.107"
        },
        {
          "currency": "ZAR",
          "rate": "15.8741"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "time": "20170810",
      "Cube": [
        {
          "currency": "USD",
          "rate": "1.1732"
        },
        {
          "currency": "JPY",
          "rate": "128.76"
        },
        {
          "currency": "BGN",
          "rate": "1.9558"
        },
        {
          "currency": "CZK",
          "rate": "26.157"
        },
        {
          "currency": "DKK",
          "rate": "7.4381"
        },
        {
          "currency": "GBP",
          "rate": "0.90303"
        },
        {
          "currency": "HUF",
          "rate": "305.37"
        },
        {
          "currency": "PLN",
          "rate": "4.2717"
        },
        {
          "currency": "RON",
          "rate": "4.5743"
        },
        {
          "currency": "SEK",
          "rate": "9.568"
        },
        {
          "currency": "CHF",
          "rate": "1.1341"
        },
        {
          "currency": "NOK",
          "rate": "9.3355"
        },
        {
          "currency": "HRK",
          "rate": "7.4008"
        },
        {
          "currency": "RUB",
          "rate": "70.2875"
        },
        {
          "currency": "TRY",
          "rate": "4.1462"
        },
        {
          "currency": "AUD",
          "rate": "1.4888"
        },
        {
          "currency": "BRL",
          "rate": "3.7024"
        },
        {
          "currency": "CAD",
          "rate": "1.4923"
        },
        {
          "currency": "CNY",
          "rate": "7.8068"
        },
        {
          "currency": "HKD",
          "rate": "9.168"
        },
        {
          "currency": "IDR",
          "rate": "15670.45"
        },
        {
          "currency": "ILS",
          "rate": "4.2182"
        },
        {
          "currency": "INR",
          "rate": "75.208"
        },
        {
          "currency": "KRW",
          "rate": "1341.21"
        },
        {
          "currency": "MXN",
          "rate": "21.0547"
        },
        {
          "currency": "MYR",
          "rate": "5.0348"
        },
        {
          "currency": "NZD",
          "rate": "1.6142"
        },
        {
          "currency": "PHP",
          "rate": "59.567"
        },
        {
          "currency": "SGD",
          "rate": "1.6"
        },
        {
          "currency": "THB",
          "rate": "39.021"
        },
        {
          "currency": "ZAR",
          "rate": "15.674"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: is there always just one object with a specific date, I guess so?

Comment: yes, they are all unique specified dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would assume, based on the data that there is always just one object with a specific date.

Then we can easily just use `find()` to get that object, and display the `rate` and `currency` of that specific date.

So your `select` stays the same, and the change event would look like this:

```
date(date) {
  this.filteredDate = this.data.find(x => x.time === date); 
}
```

Then in template we can just show the content of the array `Cube`, which is now a property of `filteredDate`. We need to of course set an `if`, that the list will not be shown, if there is no matching object. So do something like this:

```
<ion-list *ngIf="filteredDate">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of filteredDate.Cube">
    Currency: {{item.currency}}, Rate: {{item.rate}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**DEMO:** http://plnkr.co/edit/1xwhtwB5YjKHDbRzusHP?p=preview

Comment: Glad to hear! :)